# Associate an object with http session j2ee

Tags: java, session, tomcat, servlets, web

I have a `List<entity> ctx` of my `entity` class in my java web application(tomcat8, servlet3), I keep one instance for each session(user) with my context(list), and a reference copy in user's sessions, like following.

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpSession sess=request.getSession(true);
//declaring and initializing the entity object
entity e=new entity();
e.timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
//keep the e with the session
sess.setAttribute("e",e);
//and a reference copy with another context
ctx.add(e);
```

**Question:**
I just want to know(an event, listener, ...) about user http session, in order to remove the `entity` object from the `ctx` when session gets expired(removed).
Now how may I realized that a session is being expired from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `HttpSessionListener`. It exists specially for that usage. Simply override the `sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)` :

```
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    HttpSession session = se.getSession();
    // do your processing
}
@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    // empty implementation if you do not need it ...
}
```

Do not forget to declare it. Extract from javadoc : *In order to receive these notification events, the implementation class must be either declared in the deployment descriptor of the web application, annotated with WebListener, or registered via one of the addListener methods defined on ServletContext*.